# How to deal with dependencies with "provided" scope in OSGi

Tags: maven, osgi, dependency-management, bnd, maven-bundle-plugin

There are lots of tutorials, which shows how to cope with dependencies of the OSGi project and how should they be converted to the bundle. After more than one day research, I have still not found how to deal with the dependencies with `provided` scope.

Let me give an example. I am currently using `Dropbox` (dropbox-core-sdk 3.0) and it has two dependencies (`com.google.android` and `javax.servlet`) with `provided` scope. When I use the techniques such as `maven-bundle-plugin` or `bnd`, it only downloads the artifacts and its transitive dependencies. However, I need also provided dependencies in order to be able to import my project to the OSGi container.

I am using `maven-bundle-plugin` and my `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId};singleton:=true</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                    <Export-Package>*</Export-Package>
                    <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*</Embed-Dependency>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

even if `Embed-Dependency` says include everything, only the dependencies + transitive dependencies are in the jar. However, I want the provided-scoped jars are also in the jar.

Is there any way to download dependencies with `provided` scope. If not, how to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to defer to the Maven BND experts out there, but I don't think you can include provided dependencies through a Maven build. Since it is unlikely you will be using the Android components outside of your bundle, couldn't you just manually download the needed Jars and place them in your bundle (Bundle-Classpath)?

Comment: Thank you David for your answer. I have selected very bad api like dropbox to start with osgi because it is a huge library and dependency with everything. It is almost impossible to deal with all of these dependencies by hand. That is why, I wanted to automate the process.

Comment: I have downloaded the needed jars manually and placed them in my bundle but android has also thousands of dependencies (transitive + provided). I am actually stuck and do not know how to go further.

Comment: I understand, maybe the Maven BND experts can post a solution. As another approach, you could run the Dropbox project as a separate Java process and communicate with Kura via MQTT or REST. I have seen this approach used for applications that just don't fit in the OSGi architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can specify the scopes of the dependencies you want to embed. Be careful though that some dependencies like the OSGi spec jars should never be deployed.

In general you may only embed dependencies that are hidden inside the bundle. Any packages that are needed to talk to other bundles should better not deployed.

For example the servlet api is typically provided by the httpservice bundle you use.

Try this option:

`<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|provided</Embed-Dependency>`

Comment: Thanks Christian, I have editted my answer. In the configuration of the Maven, I have already said that it needs to include all dependencies.